# Composer Hangs When Updating yiisoft/yii2

Tags: cygwin, wamp, composer-php, yii2, freeze

When I run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

The process hangs.  After a few attempts and letting it sit for a while I got the following:

```
  ...
  ...
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.1)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
  The process "xcopy "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\htdocs\site
  \public_html/vendor/composer/d4dea0a0\yiisoft-yii2-framework-85b773a\captcha" "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\htdocs\site\public_html\vendor/yiisoft/yii2/captcha" /E /I /Q" exceeded the timeout of 1800 seconds.
```

I ran it twice and it failed at the same point both times.

This is on Windows using WAMP and cygwin to run the update command.

What is causing this and how do I get this working again?

Comment: Why is it looking in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\htdocs` looks like you have messed with WAMPServers config in a big way. You can also run composer from the windows command line, cygwin is only necessary to run GIT.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't recall why WAMP is configured the way it is, but running from the command prompt allowed it to install.  Must have shortened the path just enough.  Thanks!